# RDS Proxy Target groups Unavailable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, amazon-rds-proxy

I have just created RDS Proxy by Cloud Formation

In Proxies dashboard,  it showed RDS proxy is available, but Target groups are unavailable, I can't debug this and got stuck in Cloud Formation update state

This is my Cloud formation config,

I used all in-out bound traffic security group for both rds proxy and rds instance, but it doesn't seem to work...

So do I have any wrong config? I have stuck at this  all day

```yml
RDSInstance:
  DependsOn: DBSecurityGroup
  Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
  Properties: 
    AllocatedStorage: '20'
    AllowMajorVersionUpgrade: false
    AutoMinorVersionUpgrade: true
    AvailabilityZone: ${self:provider.region}a
    DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
    DBName: mydb
    VPCSecurityGroups: 
      - "Fn::GetAtt": [ DBSecurityGroup, GroupId ]
    Engine: postgres
    EngineVersion: '11.9'
    MasterUsername: postgres
    MasterUserPassword: Fighting001
    PubliclyAccessible: true
    DBSubnetGroupName: 
      Ref: DBSubnetGroup
    # VPCSecurityGroups: 
    #   Ref: VPC
DBSecretsManager:
  Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
  Properties: 
    Description: 'Secret Store for database connection'
    Name: postgres
    SecretString: 
      'password'
RDSProxy:
  DependsOn: DBSecurityGroup
  Type: AWS::RDS::DBProxy
  Properties: 
    Auth: 
      - AuthScheme: SECRETS
        SecretArn: 
          Ref: DBSecretsManager
        IAMAuth: DISABLED
    DBProxyName: ${self:provider.stackName}-db-proxy
    DebugLogging: true
    EngineFamily: 'POSTGRESQL'
    RoleArn: 'my role arn'
    VpcSecurityGroupIds: 
    - "Fn::GetAtt": [ DBSecurityGroup, GroupId ]
    VpcSubnetIds: 
      - Ref: PublicSubnetA
      - Ref: PublicSubnetB
RDSProxyTargetGroup:
  Type: AWS::RDS::DBProxyTargetGroup
  Properties:
    DBProxyName: 
      Ref: RDSProxy
    DBInstanceIdentifiers: [Ref: RDSInstance]
    TargetGroupName: "default"
    ConnectionPoolConfigurationInfo:
        MaxConnectionsPercent: 45
        MaxIdleConnectionsPercent: 40
        ConnectionBorrowTimeout: 120
```

Comment: What about the IAM roles? They are not shown.

Comment: For rds proxy? It can access all secrect manager value as well. Sr i'm on phone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A likely reason why your template fails is that your `AWS::SecretsManager::Secret` is not used and has incorrect values.

Your DB uses:

```
    MasterUsername: postgres
    MasterUserPassword: Fighting001
```

But your `DBSecretsManager` is:

```
SecretString: 
     'password'
```

which is incorrect. I would suggest setting up manually everything in the AWS console first. Then you can check what is the **correct form** of the `SecretString` for your use-case.

Comment: I just saw that. Look like that why. Tks u. I will update later

Comment: Second update, sr i forgot to write
I need convert SecretString to JSON type string 
SecretString: 
          '{"username":"yourdbusername","password":"password"}'
remember this is JSON type string

Answer (score 3):

While this isnt the cause of the original issue mentioned above, it may help someone who reaches this post in future.

Make sure your RDS instance and the security group associated with it are using the same port.

I experienced the same outcome because my RDS security group was configured using a different port than the RDS instance.

By default, Aurora Postgres will use port `3306`, however my security group was using `5432` (because it was copied from an old Postgres non-Aurora RDS instance). I updated my RDS instance to use port `5432` by specifying the `Port` property which resolved this issue.

Comment: Nice! You wrote the right sentence and made my RDS Proxy Available, thanks!